# Solving a definite integral using Integration by parts [simple]

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is to evaluate this integral:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 ye^{-3y} dy$

I have uploaded an image of my work as well as my attempt to make my writing clearer in Paint.

[image: what]!

Thanks so much for any help, not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: oh crap, in the first line which i wrote in paint, it should be (-1/3)y times e^-3y.... thats not my error i just wrote it down for you guys wrong

Comment: Surely if it were simple you wouldn't be asking here? xD

Comment: Haha, well I thought it was very simple when I first started it, and when I finished it I thought it was simple; but my answer was determined to be wrong. I can't find out what I did wrong lol

Comment: So I'm assuming you have the correct answer available to you? What does your book say is the correct answer?

Comment: No, it's a problem in my online homework list. It said my answer was wrong. I have unlimited chances but I dont know what else to submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did the "hard part" correctly. You erred at the very end, after evaluating the integral at the bounds of integration. The following is correct:

> $$-\frac{1}{3e^3} - \left(\dfrac 1{9e^3} - \dfrac 19\right)$$

But, you need to distribute the negative over the parenthetical expression, to obtain $$-\dfrac{4}{9e^3} + \dfrac 19$$

Comment: Ah thanks, I should have seen that... I'd give you reputation but I'm not sure how aha

Comment: Your welcome. I hope you at least feel relieved that you nailed the integration by parts!

Comment: @amWhy: Answer needs another TU! +1